# Magento loadByAttribute for Custom Category Attributes

Tags: magento, custom-attributes, categories

I have created custom attributes for a category in my module's install script like so:

```
$attrib = array(
        'type'          => 'varchar',
        'group'         => 'My Data',
        'backend'       => '',
        'frontend'      => '',
        'label'         => 'My Custom Field',
        'input'         => 'text',
        'class'         => '',
        'source'        => '',
        'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'visible'       => true,
        'required'      => false,
        'user_defined'  => false,
        'default'       => '',
        'searchable'    => false,
        'filterable'    => false,
        'comparable'    => false,
        'visible_on_front' => false,
        'unique'        => true,
    );
$installer->addAttribute(3, 'custom_field', $attrib);
```

The field shows up fine in the admin, and when I create the category in my script like so:

```
$p_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
            ->setStoreId(0)
            ->load(2);
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category->setStoreId(0)
    ->setName('Test Category')
    ->setCustomField('abcd')
    ->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS')
    ->setAttributeSetId($category->getDefaultAttributeSetId())
    ->setIsActive(1)
    ->setIsAnchor(1)
    ->setPath(implode('/',$p_category->getPathIds()))
    ->setInitialSetupFlag(true)
    ->save();
```

I can see the value 'abcd' in the Magneto admin interface.  But when I call the code below:

```
<?php
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->loadByAttribute('custom_field', 'abcd');
print_r($category);
?>
```

I get no result.  But if I loadByAttribute using the 'name' field set to 'Test Category', I DO get a result.

So, in the database, I looked into the `catalog_category_entity_varchar` table and noticed that the 'name' attribute had an entry for both store_id = 0 AND store_id = 1 whereas the 'custom_field' attribute had only an entry for store_id = 1.

When I added a store_id = 0 entry for 'custom_field' with the value set to 'abcd' in the `catalog_category_entity_varchar` table, loadByAttribute got the expected result.

My question is, why is the 'name' field getting a store_id = 0 entry in `catalog_category_entity_varchar` and my custom field is not?
How do I load categories by custom attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running 1.4.1.1 and noticed a similar issue with a custom product attribute. If you filter a collection by an attribute that attribute has to have a value for the default store as well as the store you're interested in.  You can see why if you do the following

```
Mage::Log($collection->getSelect()->__toString());
```

When you look at the query in the log file you'll see that magneto does an inner join onto the  attribute table for store_id 0, so if you haven't created a value for store zero it can't give you a result. Seems like a bug to me, I think Magento should do a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the following key to global then it should add it for both stores

```
 'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
```

Answer (score 1):

More a guess here than knowing anything for sute, as you have a lot going on and I'm not sure if I follow your concern about the store_id (not that it's a valid concern, I'm just not sure where it enters the picture)

When you setup your attribute, you used

```
'filterable'    => false,
```

try setting up a new attribute with this set to true.  If you look at the `loadByAttribute` source code, it's using attribute filtering to work, so you'll need filterable attributes if you want to use this method.

Comment: I tried and still no luck.  I think the store_id has something to do with whether or not the attribute is accessible.  Like I said, adding the entry with store_id = 0 allowed me to load as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the cache before loading the model with custom attribute , loadByAttribute works fine.